# Why does my Ajax post have content when going to backend but my model and controller receive null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

AJAX Post shows correct content in debugger but my controller and model receive null values.

I have changed my ajax post many ways. I have also just sent one string and had one string as my controller parameter. This worked, but I am looking to send the whole object.

```
        var BuildContent = [{ 'Cal': Cal, 'BarLength': BarLength, 'Color': 
        Color }];
        content = JSON.stringify(BuildContent);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../Build/Build",
            data: {'content':content},
            ContentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
        });
```

```
    public class BuildController : Controller
    {


        [HttpPost]
        public BuildContent Build (BuildContent content) 
        {
            //BuildService.GetURG(data);
            return content;
        }
    }
```

```
    public class BuildContent
    {

        public string Cal { get; set; }
        public string BarLength { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
```

SO when the POST reaches the controller I am seeing [Cal = null , BarLength = null, Color = null]
Where as in the Chrome network debugger I see my content correctly. Such as 
content: [{"Cal":"5.56","BarLength":"16\"","Color":"Black"}]

Comment: Why do you wrap your content in the `content` property? What happens if you just use `data: content`?

Comment: I had it wrapped in content just from trying different things. Removing it leaves me with the same problem albeit it changes the post from 
content: [{"Cal":"5.56","BarLength":"16\"","Color":"Black"}]
to [{"Cal":"5.56","BarLength":"16\"","Color":"Black"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending an array of objects, only a single one. So there's no need to surround your object in an array initialiser.

Below I've created a JavaScript object and then converted it into JSON.
Try this and let me know how it goes.

```
var buildContent = {'Cal': 'Testing123...', 'BarLength': 'Noot Noot', 'Color': 'Red'};
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(buildContent);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Build/Build",
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json;'
});
```

EDIT:
Alternatively try sending the object in its entirety, without serializing it to JSON.

```
var buildContent = {'Cal': 'Testing123...', 'BarLength': 'Noot Noot', 'Color': 'Red'};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Build/Build",
    data: buildContent
});
```

Comment: I made the changes yet, I am still stuck with the results being null. I appreciate the help though. Is there something I should be including in the model or controller that I am not ?
```Currently my model has:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;```
```
And my controller has 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using modelnamespace```

Comment: I've edited my solution - try sending the object in its entirety without serializing it.
If that doesn't work I'm happy to help over teamviewer or something if need be :)

Comment: That fixed it! I have been on this issue for longer than I would like to admit. So when would be the proper time to serialize the data? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That happens to all of us, don't worry!

It seems that jQuery will serialize the data parameter itself using its default Key/Value pair serializer. 
So you should be fine with sending objects all the time really.